# Custom expand/collapse menu list collapses when clicking on list items

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I've made a custom expand/collapse list in `css` and `javascript`.
Here is my code:

```
componentDidMount() {
var togglerCons = document.getElementsByClassName("caretCons");
    var c;

    for (c = 0; c < togglerCons.length; c++) {
      togglerCons[c].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.parentElement
          .querySelector(".nestedCons")
          .classList.toggle("activeCons");
        this.classList.toggle("caretCons-down");
      });
    }
```

```
  <li className="caretCons">
                <Link to={"/ConsignmentList"}>
                  <span
                    onClick={() =>
                      this.props.updateTypeOfConsignmentList("general")
                    }
                  >
                    {content[lang].consignmentlist}
                  </span>
                </Link>
                <ul className="nestedCons">
                  <li onClick={this.getConsPerDepot}>
                    {content[lang].consPerDepot}
                  </li>
                  <li onClick={this.getExpectedCons}>
                    {content[lang].expected}
                  </li>
                  <li onClick={this.getAssignedCons}>
                    {content[lang].assigned}
                  </li>
                  <li onClick={this.getUnassignedCons}>
                    {content[lang].unassigned}
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>


}
```

Here is the result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlBzT.png

Here is what happens when clicking on the 'Consignment List': https://i.stack.imgur.com/07oPN.png

Everything's as expected until here. The problem is that when user clicks on one of the list items under Consignment List (expected, assigned etc) the list collapses and becomes like the first photo. What I want is for the list to remain expanded and not to collapse when user clicks on a list item. It should collapse only when user clicks on the caret symbol (little triangle).

This is the css

```
.caretCons {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari 3.1+ */
  -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox 2+ */
  -ms-user-select: none; /* IE 10+ */
  user-select: none;
}

.caretCons::before {
  content: "\25B6";
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 6px;
}

.caretCons-down::before {
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); 
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); 
  transform: rotate(90deg);  
}

.nestedCons {
  display: none;
}

.activeCons {
  display: block;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your issues is that you are adding event listeners directly to DOM elements which is something you should not do when using React , unless it's absolutely necessary for some reason.
You should use the React's `onClick` attribute instead, just like you are doing below on your list items.

Now, about the lists collapsing when you click an inner element, you might want to look at [event bubbling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_bubbling_and_capture)
as well as `Event.stopPropagation` which is referenced [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

Good luck!